# Чи потрібно ставити кому після слова “отож”?

Tags: пунктуація

У методичці для учителя [Читання. 4 клас: Авторські уроки](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=2tCst0jGs4oC&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6,+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=M4kCP7FZbY&sig=ESPWFYQazB2_cD4Irtgi6iG3BQY&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvts-Hm-fbAhWsw6YKHZjaAyIQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5&f=false) випадково помітила речення, в якому слово “***отож***” виділено комою:

> **Отож,** читайте, слухайте, смійтеся собі на радість.

На іншому сайті знайшла післямову Івана Андрусяка [Коли по землі ходили гіганти](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=SHxFBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6,+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=G9O6SmajbZ&sig=UaQoUc96yabtuP507imnlW2_T3I&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvts-Hm-fbAhWsw6YKHZjaAyIQ6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5&f=false), в якій немає подібного виділення:

> **Отож** читайте, насолоджуйтеся — і переконуйтеся.

Цікавить, чи потрібно ставити кому після слова “***отож***”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Отож** не є вставним словом, тому і не виділяється комою.

Ніколи не бувають [вставними](http://shkolyar.in.ua/vstani-rechennya)  слова майже, навіть, мовби, нібито, причому, приблизно, притому, при цьому, все-таки, саме, якраз, просто, тобто, адже, буквально, принаймні, особливо, **отож**, тож, тільки.

Ці слова  виступають у ролі **[службових](https://studfiles.net/preview/5115587/page:28/)  частин мови.**