# Відсутність коми у реченні з XX всеукраїнського диктанту

Tags: пунктуація

*Отож(,) доки Ілон Маск ще тільки на півдорозі до інших світів, паперова книжка в безпеці.*

Після "отож" по логіці має бути кома, бо головне речення - "*Отож паперова книжка в безпеці*", а підрядне речення починається з "*доки*".
Чи за правилами те, що там кома відсутня (може, це пов'язано з новим правописом), чи там помилка?

Comment: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4399/585

Comment: @stegetsj Це не те, в нас тут відсутність коми перед підрядним реченням, а не просто після "отож".

Answer (score 3):

Я не знаю правил, які дозволяли б у таком випадку пропускати кому.

Хоча на практиці її часто пропускають, наприклад, у «ГРАК-10» на [7-8 випадків «Отож, доки…»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6+,+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) бачу [6 випадків «Отож доки…»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) (і в усіх них та сама ситуація — з «доки» починається пядрядне речення, після якого йде головне) і на [14 випадків «Тому, доки…»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+,+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) (доволі схожа ситуація) — [12-13 випадків «Тому доки…»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Я не спеціаліст-мовознавець, тому моє рішення не можна вважати остаточним, але таке пропускання коми здається радше поширеною помилкою, ніж чимось дозволеним.

Comment: В російській мові те ж саме.

Comment: @oled, так. (Я навіть передивився деякі фрагменти http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php і http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php перед тим, як відповідати — у російській мові часто подібні пунктуаційні правила, але іноді вони ретельніше розписані — але не знайшов нічого, що б могло виправдати відсутність коми в цьому випадку бодай у російській мові.)

Comment: Просто там всі правила вказують на те, що кома не ставиться після сполучника, якщо після підрядного речення йде частка "*то*". Але ще в Розенталя вказано, що кома зазвичай не ставиться після "*але*" на початку речення, і цей випадок також є в цьому диктанті (*Але коли*).

Comment: @oleedd, іще в деяких випадках можна пропускати коми після сполучника _а_ і/або між сполучником та сполучним словом (принаймні в російській мові — [§ 68](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg68.php), [§ 123.3](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg123.php))… Але по-моєму, це все не те…

Comment: @oleedd, щодо «після але», то про це в правописі 2019 [написано так](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=182): «Якщо перший сполучник при цьому є протиставним (а, але, однак і т. ін.), коми після нього взагалі не ставимо: Він прокинувся увечері, <…> довго пив чай, а коли зовсім стемніло, став збиратися у свою п’яту вилазку (Л. Первомайський)». Але _[отож](http://sum.in.ua/s/otozh)_ аж ніяк не протиставний.

Comment: Бо якщо в цих випадках підрядне вилучити (без сполучника), то вийде нісенітниця. Якщо є кома, то має бути пауза та логічний наголос перед комою. У випадку з "і" це звучить дуже недоречно, тому є правило. А у випадку з "отож" - доречно.

Comment: @oleedd, я трішки заплутався — що саме у випадку «і» дуже недоречно, а у випадку «отож» доречно?

Comment: Робити після них паузу, через що на них падає логічний наголос.